# Fill HTML form with PHP array using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, forms

I'm looking for a simple way to do this.

Consider this PHP array of my favorite fruits, in descending order of like:

```
$fruits = array('Banana', 'Orange', 'Rasberry');
```

Consider this HTML form:

```
<form action="" method="get">
What's your name?<br />
<input type="text" name="name" />
Name your favorite fruit<br />
<input type="text" name="favorite" /><br />
Choose a fruit you like<br />
<select name="oneyoulike">
<option value="Blueberry">Blueberry</option>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>
</form>
```

I want to "auto-fill" this HTML form after I entered my name. So that input text `favorite` would show `Banana` or `$fruits[0]` and `<select>` would show `Orange` because it is the only match with the `$fruits` array.

Comment: what about Raspberry ? it is not a fruit ? You can insert your data in  PHP tags like in `<input type="text" name="favorite"  value="<?php echo $fruits[0]; ?>"/>`. If you need to do such a job dynamically, you will need to use ajax

Comment: Yeah it is. Just for the purpose of the example. I looking for dynamic because `$fruits` array depends on the `name`. But thanks for the hint.

Comment: So, you have to add a listener on your input, and at each change, call an ajax refresh that will refresh the select :)